# How to find $\int {t^n \, e^{t}}\mathrm dt$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider:$$\int {t^n  e^{t}}\ \mathrm dt$$
is there any closed formula for this?
W|A gave me this but I don't know what is Gamma function:
$$\int {t^n e^t\ \mathrm dt} = (-t)^{-n}\ t^n\ \Gamma(n+1, -t)+ \text{constant}$$

Comment: When I type `integrate t^n Exp[t]` it returns an answer along with the text "$\Gamma(a,x)$ is the incomplete gamma function"; if you hover over this text it will provide you with links to Documentation, Properties, and Definition. Here special functions are unavoidable.

Comment: Without knowledge of the incomplete Gamma function, you can integrate by parts $n$ times, with which you can derive a formula by induction. In the case of the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ (the complete Gamma function), this is used to show that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$.

Comment: apply partial integration n times to get rid of the polynomial and exponential combination. good luck.

Comment: Your problems may originate from the fact that W|A doesn't know that $n$ is a positive integer. Try this with $n=2$, $n=3$ et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assuming $n$ is a positive integer, there is a closed formula including a sum
$$\int t^n e^t \mathrm{d}t = n!e^t\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}\frac{t^k}{k!} + C $$
I got it by using the formulas [(1)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E9) and [(2)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E11) for the incomplete Gamma function. Once you have it,  it can be verified by taking the derivative or you can try proving it with mathematical induction.

Answer (score 0):

It is easily proved by induction and integration by parts that
$$
\int {t^n  e^{t}}\,dt = p_n(t) e^t
$$
where $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and
$$
p_{n+1}(t) = t^{n+1}-(n+1)p_n(t)
$$
This will give you the formula mentioned by gammatester.